# Converting a string to slug comparing with a given array of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a string containing `hello world`. I want to make it unique comparing the array of string like this:

```
[
   'hello-world', 
   'hello-world-1', 
   'hello-world-2',
   'hello-world-3', 
   'hello-world-4', 
   'hello-world-5'
]
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Please include some code to show you have at least attempted to resolve this yourself before asking your question here.

Comment: This isn't a proper question. Objective is not clear whatsoever.

Comment: Can't understand what "make it unique comparing the array" means.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it following way

```
    function slugify(string , keys ){
      var inArray = isInArray(string , keys);    
      if(inArray == true){
        var lastcharacter = string.slice(-1);
        if(!isNaN(lastcharacter)){
            var addOne = parseInt(lastcharacter) + parseInt(1);
            var newCheck = string.slice(0,-1).concat(parseInt(addOne));
            slugify(newCheck , keys);            
        }else{
            var addOne = string.concat('-1');
            slugify(addOne , keys);
        }
      }else{        
        var checkWhiteSpace = hasWhiteSpace(string);        
        if(checkWhiteSpace == true){
            var whiteSpace = string.replace(/ /g,'-');
            slugify(whiteSpace , keys);
        }else{
            keys.push(string);            
        }      
      }

      return keys;
    }

    function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
     return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
    }
    function isInArray(value, array) {
     return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }

    var slugLists = slugify(string , keys);
    console.log(slugLists);
```

**check this result in console in jsfiddle**
[result here](http://jsfiddle.net/roman083047/L3p5bh97/1/)

Comment: You can remove some `parseInt` calls. See [my fork](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/2muwevru/1/).